# Can you vote to undelete my question so I can put a bounty on it?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-undelete

[My question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49278648) was automatically deleted by Community. I'd like to undelete it so I can set a bounty on it and see if it attracts answers. I could simply reask it, but a moderator made many changes that improved the question and I think it's unfair to reask and erase his contribution.

If you think the question is OK, please upvote it so Community won't delete it again soon (it has -2 votes at the moment, it needs 0). Honestly, I think it was first downvoted by people who didn't understand JavaScript and what was being asked. They thought I ignored something I explicitly put as an incorrect sollution, but my wording wasn't good at the time, perhaps.

Thanks!

EDIT: Just to be clear, I wouldn't usually assume that people downvoted my question because they didn't understand JavaScript nor my brilliance or whatever. The reason I'm assuming they didn't know JavaScript is that there was a highly voted comment telling me to use `event.key`, but I had already said in my original phrasing of the question that `event.key` wouldn't work, and I explained why. But this comment was deleted after the question had been downvoted a lot, so one who reads the question now might not know this.

EDIT2: I did Google, I don't know why one would think I didn't. And I also searched SO for it. The main problem is that most of the solutions also suggest deprecated methods ([for example, see this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45774330/4621141)), so it doesn't solve the deprecation problem. If you *did* find a sollution, I'd be very grateful if you could point me to it, but I honestly couldn'y find one, that's why I asked here.

Comment: _"Honestly, I think it was first downvoted by people who didn't understand JavaScript"_ Honestly, I think you should never assume that.

Comment: @E_net4 you're right, I would *usually* not assume that. I only assumed this due to the comments that were deleted afterwards. There was a highly voted comment telling me I should use `event.key`, but I didn't use it because I specified in the question that it didn't work

Comment: Use Google first, I recommend "keyboardevent.which non-deprecated alternative".  SO hits are first, I see 5 matching hits on just the first page of them.  If they don't help you somehow then ask the question again, be sure to reference the existing solutions and explain what's wrong with them.  Demonstrate any "it didn't work" code with a runnable snippet.

Comment: @HansPassant I did google, which SO questions are you talking about? The ones I found were irrelevant to what I asked, like this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41266964/is-there-an-alternative-to-deprecated-e-which-in-javascript . Sorry if there was already an alternative, but I didn't find it, I'd appreciate if you could point me to one

Comment: It is *your* job to state the reason they don't solve your problem.  Not mine, I don't do [javascript] and don't need this problem solved.  Don't just pick off one, even I can tell that you are not fretting about the mouse.

Comment: @HansPassant would you suggest me to reword something I said in the question? You're certainly not suggesting me to pick random questions and say why they don't work for me. It's stated in the question that `event.keyCode` for example is deprecated and that `event.which` is not the same as `event.key`. I'm sorry, but if you're saying I didn't google, it's *your* job to prove it

Comment: I like the edit description *"Tried to get rid of more senseless downvoters"*. I'm not sure if that exactly describes what you intended to do. If it is true then let me put you on a list of names of people I stay very far away from :)

Comment: @Gimby interpretation needs context. IIRC, when I made that edit there was a comment saying+-: "MDN says you can substitute `event.which` for `event.key`. You should just read MDN and not ask this". In +- 5 minutes, this comment had 7 upvotes, while my question had 3 or 5 downvotes. In my question, I originally specified that `event.key` was *not* the same as `event.which`. MDN must be read with a grain of salt; it didn't say they were interchangeable, but rather that you could, in some cases, use one instead of the other. Downvoting because you don't know JS is what I call "senseless"

Comment: @flen Interpretation? That edit description just says you're killing downvoters.

Comment: @Gimby got it;) I don't think the question was bad enough to kill them though, no matter how hard I tried. But I guess you can see why I was aprehensive, it's a scary question apparently, and just invoking it in this meta got -17 phantoms

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I feel that this question has potential after the edit, as the problem is specific and reproducible. I'm giving this another chance with a bounty.